# How to configure public ip on azure

Tags: azure

I have configure public ip on azure in my environment but when i check outside this environment it's not working so my question is how to set globally public ip on azure.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add two more tips, to check the public IP address works, you need open NSG inbound rule (3389 for RDP), also use [PSPing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psping.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of ICMP PING tool.

Answer (score -1):

Just login to portal. select VM. In settings go to PIP (Public IP)
Mark for it. This is you have done.
Now check whether you have open ports and IPs for same under NSG or sort of security groups. If it is public IP then you should be able to ping.
Please check for same.

Thanks

Comment: This is incorrect. ICMP is not permitted from outside of Azure.